# Compare multiple columns to multiple columns in 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

`Table1` has `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`, `tag4` … to `tag15`
`Table2` has `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`, `tag4` … to `tag15`

I need a SQL select statement to pull all records where ANY tags match.

Tong way would be something like:

```
SELECT table1.*
WHERE table1.tag1 = table2.tag1
   OR table1.tag1 = table2.tag2
   OR table1.tag1 = table2.tag3
```

(For every tag.)

Any efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think 225 OR statements is your only way... if you post your schema we can probably give you a saner way to store your data.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? It's hard to try and figure out what might work without know what the data looks like.

Comment: No efficient way but a for loop will do the trick like `'tag'.$i`

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lousy data structure.  The tags should be stored in a separate table, with one row per item and tag -- so a given row might have 15 tags.  Then the query would be pretty simple.

One way to simplify your query is to use `in`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     tabl2 t2
     on t1.tag1 in (t2.tag1, t2.tag3, . . . , t2.tag15) or
        t1.tag2 in ( . . . ) or
        . . .
```

I think this will even work for `NULL` values in the tags.

EDIT:

A comma separated list is even worse than separate columns.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
on find_in_set(substring_index(t1.tags, ',', 1), t2.tags) > 0 or
   find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(t1.tags, ',', 2), -1), t2.tags) > 0 or
   find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(t1.tags, ',', 3), -1), t2.tags) > 0 or
   . . .
```

The right way is to have two tables with columns like:

- Table1id
- Tag

And

- Table2id
- tag

Then the query is:

```
select *
from table1tags t1t join
     table2tags t2t
     on t1t.tag = t2t.tag;
```

Much simpler than the other alternatives.

Comment: I actually simplified my tables (still not good data structure, I know) but I have tags in 1 comma separated field if table1 and table2. How would I use IN to compare any word in table1.tags with any word in table2.tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN operator.

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
JOIN table2
WHERE table1.tag1 IN (table2.tag1,table2.tag2,table2.tag3...table2.tag15) OR
table1.tag2 IN (table2.tag1,table2.tag2,table2.tag3...table2.tag15) OR
table1.tag3 IN (table2.tag1,table2.tag2,table2.tag3...table2.tag15) OR
...
...
table1.tag15 IN (table2.tag1,table2.tag2,table2.tag3...table2.tag15)
```

It's the same as saying

```
WHERE 
table1.tag1 = table2.tag1 OR 
table1.tag1 = table2.tag2 OR
...
table1.tag2 = table2.tag2 OR 
...
table1.tag2 = table2.tag15 OR
... 
table1.tag15 = table2.tag15
```

Only a lot less lines.